# perfomance problems with mysql and apache on windows

Tags: php, mysql, windows, apache, performance

**Has no one an idea what maybe can help me to find out the reason for this problem???**

I wrote a web application for a non-profit project. We have twice a year a market here we sell used children's clothing and toys. People bring us their goods and we manage all the selling and get a fee for children projects in our town.

My scripts and the database is working good but i have some performance problems. We can do 5-10 booking without any problems and the the script hangs. We do the booking by scanning a barcode (script 1). Script 2 is looking for the right price and writes an entry in the mysql database. If we don't have a problem the booking is done just after the scan (less than a second).

My problem is that I don't have any idea where we have the problem.

If I test the application only on my localhost I cannot see any problems and it does not hang. Only when connection over the network. Then I'm able to do 10 bookings and suddenly it stops working / loading in background. After a refresh of the page it starts working again. I'm not sure that the problem is the apache or mysql-server or the script. Maybe I have a network problem?

Has anyone an idea how i can find out which causes the performance problems?

Server? Apache? mysql?
Router? switch?
Clients?

Thank you a thousand times in advance for all your assistance and help?

We do about 3-4 booking in a second. All Computer are used and five years or older (also the server). It's 1 server and 3 clients computers (all Windows 7 Pro). I'm using chrome as browser. I have one router and an unmanaged switch for the network connection. No other computers are in the network.

here are the the two php-scripts for the bookings:

```
<html>  
<head>  
<title>Erfassung Kassenvorgänge</title>  
<script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script> 
<!--
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
-->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />  
</head>
<body> 
<?php
include 'connectdb.php';
$ShowDebugInfo = false;
if ($ShowDebugInfo) {
    print "\$_SESSION: ";
    print_r($_SESSION);
    print "<br>\n";
    print "\$_POST: ";
    print_r($_POST);
    print "<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>\n";
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['KasseNr'])) {
    print "KasseNr nicht gesetzt!<br>\n";
    if (!$ShowDebugInfo) {die(header('Location: basar_zeigen.php'));}
} else {
    $KasseNr = @$_SESSION['KasseNr'];
}
$_SESSION['KasseNr'] = $KasseNr;
if (!isset($_SESSION['idBasar'])) {
    print "idBasar nicht gesetzt!<br>\n";
    if (!$ShowDebugInfo) {die(header('Location: basar_zeigen.php'));}
} else {
    $BasarNr = @$_SESSION['idBasar'];
}
$_SESSION['idBasar'] = $BasarNr;
if (!isset($_SESSION['Basar_DT'])) {
    print "Basar_DT nicht gesetzt!<br>\n";
    if (!$ShowDebugInfo) {die(header('Location: basar_zeigen.php'));}
} else {
    $Datum = @$_SESSION['Basar_DT'];
}

if ($ShowDebugInfo) {print "isValidTimeStamp? " . isTimestamp($Datum) . "<br>\n";}
if (isTimestamp($Datum)) {
    if ($ShowDebugInfo) {print "Timestamp!<br>\n";}
    $BasarDt = date( 'd.m.Y', $Datum);
    $BasarDatum = date( 'd.m.Y', $Datum);
    $BasarDtkurz = date( 'd.m.y', $Datum);
} else {
    if ($ShowDebugInfo) {print "String!<br>\n";}
    $BasarDt = date( 'd.m.Y', strtotime($Datum));
    $BasarDatum = date( 'd.m.Y', strtotime($Datum));
    $BasarDtkurz = date( 'd.m.y', strtotime($Datum));
}

$SummeAlt = @$_SESSION['SummeAlt'];
if ($ShowDebugInfo) {
    print "<p>Datum: " . $Datum ."</p>\n";
    print "<p>BasarDt: " . $BasarDt ."</p>\n";
    print "<p>BasarDatum: " . $BasarDatum ."</p>\n";
    print "<p>BasarDtkurz: " . $BasarDtkurz ."</p>\n";
    print "<p>Kasse-Nr: " . $KasseNr ."</p>\n";
    print "<p>Summe letzter Vorgang: " . $SummeAlt ."</p>\n";
}
$sql ="SELECT max(Vorgang) as maxVorgang FROM ksb.umsatz_" . $BasarNr . " where idKasse='" . $KasseNr . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$Count=0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $VorgangNeu = $row['maxVorgang'] + 1;
    $VorgangAlt = $row['maxVorgang'];
    $Count++;
}
if ($Count !=1) {
    die(print "<b>Fehler beim Auslesen der neuen Vorgangsnummer!");
}
if (isset($_SESSION['Neu'])) {
    switch ($_SESSION['Neu']) {
        case 1:
            $Vorgang = $VorgangNeu;
            $LfdNr = 1;
            $_SESSION['Neu'] = 0;
            break;
        case 0:
            $Vorgang = $VorgangAlt;
            if (isset($_POST["V"])) {
                $Vorgang = $_POST["V"];
                unset($_POST);
            }
            if (!isset($_SESSION['VorgangLfdNr'])) {
                $sql ="SELECT max(VorgangLfdNr) as maxLfdNr FROM ksb.umsatz_" . $BasarNr . " where idKasse='" . $KasseNr . "' AND Vorgang=" . $Vorgang;
                print $sql;
                $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
                $Count=0;
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                    $LfdNrNeu = $row['maxLfdNr'] + 1;
                    $LfdNrAlt = $row['maxLfdNr'];
                    $Count++;
                }
                if ($Count !=1) {
                    die(print "<b>Fehler beim Auslesen der neuen Vorgangsnummer!");
                }
                $LfdNr = $LfdNrNeu;
            } else {
                $LfdNr = $_SESSION['VorgangLfdNr']+1;
            }
            break;
    }
} else {
    $sql2 ="SELECT max(VorgangLfdNr) as maxLfdNr FROM ksb.umsatz_" . $BasarNr . " where idKasse='" . $KasseNr . "' AND Vorgang='" . $VorgangAlt . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql2);
    $Count=0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $LfdNrNeu = $row['maxLfdNr'] + 1;
        $LfdNrAlt = $row['maxLfdNr'];
        $Count++;
    }
    $Vorgang = $VorgangAlt;
    if ($Vorgang==0) {
        $Vorgang=1;
    }       
    $LfdNr = $LfdNrNeu;
}
if ($ShowDebugInfo) {
    print_r(@$_POST);
    print "<br>\n";
    print "<p>VorgangNeu: " . $VorgangNeu ."</p>\n";
    print "<p>VorgangAlt: " . $VorgangAlt ."</p>\n";
    print "<p>LfdNrNeu: " . $LfdNrNeu ."</p>\n";
    print "<p>LfdNrAlt: " . $LfdNrAlt ."</p>\n";
    print "<p>LfdNr: " . $LfdNr ."</p>\n";

}
function isTimestamp($string)
{
    try {
        new DateTime('@' . $string);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
?>
<?php include 'nav.php'?>
<div id="Eingabe" class="container">  
<br />  
<br />  
<h2 align="center">Erfassung Kassenvorgänge</h2>
<h3 align="center">Basar am <?php print $BasarDatum ?> / <b>Kasse Nr. <?php print $KasseNr ?></b></h3>
<hr>
<div class="form-group">  
<form name="neuer_Vorgang" id="neuer_Vorgang">  
<div id="Meldung" name="Meldung" class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="alert alert-success Info" id="Info" name="Info" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="table-responsive">  
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
<tr>
<td>Vorgang Nr.</td>  
<td>lfd. Nr</td>
<td>Artikel</td>    
<td>Preis</td>                               
<td>&nbsp;</td><!-- löschen -->
<td>&nbsp;</td><!-- bearbeiten -->
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td><input type="hidden" name="BasarDatum" placeholder="BasarDatum" class="form-control name_list" value="<?php print $BasarDtkurz ?>" readonly /><input type="hidden" name="idBasar" placeholder="idBasar" class="form-control name_list" value="<?php print $BasarNr ?>" readonly /><input type="hidden" name="idKasse" placeholder="idKasse" class="form-control name_list" value="<?php print $KasseNr ?>" readonly /><input type="text" name="Vorgang" placeholder="Vorgang" class="form-control name_list" value="<?php print $Vorgang ?>" readonly /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="idlfdNr" placeholder="idlfdNr" class="form-control name_list" readonly value="<?php print $LfdNr ?>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" id="Artikel" name="Artikel" placeholder="Artikel" pattern="[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}" class="form-control name_list" onchange="checkcode('1')" /></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td><!-- Preis   -->
<td>&nbsp;</td><!-- löschen -->
<td>&nbsp;</td><!-- bearbeiten -->
<!--
<td><input type="number" id="Preis1" name="Preis" id="Preis" placeholder="Preis" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
<td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">+</button></td>
-->
</tr>
<?php
$sql ="SELECT * FROM ksb.umsatz_" . $BasarNr . " where idKasse='" . $KasseNr . "' AND Vorgang='" . $Vorgang . "' ORDER BY Zeitstempel DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$Count=0;
$Summe=0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    if ($row['geandert']==1) {
        $Info =" &sup1;";
    } else {
        $Info ="";
    }
    print "<tr>\n";
    print "<td><input type='text' readonly class='form-control name_list' value='" . $row['Vorgang'] . "'</td>\n";
    print "<td><input type='text' readonly class='form-control name_list' value='" . $row['VorgangLfdNr'] . "'</td>\n";
    print "<td><input type='text' readonly class='form-control name_list' value='" . $row['Artikel'] . "'</td>\n";
    print "<td><input type='text' readonly class='form-control name_list' value='" . number_format(($row['Preis']),2,',','.') . " €" . $Info . "'</td>\n";
    print "<td><button type='button' value='X' name='remove' id='remove_" . $row['idBasar'] . "_" . $row['idKasse'] . "_" . $row['Vorgang'] . "_" . $row['VorgangLfdNr'] . "' class='btn btn-danger btn_remove'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button></td>\n";
    print "<td><button type='button' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#vorgang_edit' data-btnname='edit' value='E' name='edit' id='edit_" . $row['idBasar'] . "_" . $row['idKasse'] . "_" . $row['Vorgang'] . "_" . $row['VorgangLfdNr'] . "' data-id='edit_" . $row['idBasar'] . "_" . $row['idKasse'] . "_" . $row['Vorgang'] . "_" . $row['VorgangLfdNr'] . "_" . $row['Artikel'] . "_" . number_format(($row['Preis']),2,',','.') . "' class='btn btn-warning btn_edit open-EditDialog'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></button></td>\n";
    print "</tr>\n";
    $Summe+=$row['Preis'];
}
?>
</table>  
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td align="left" width="25%"><button type="button" name="manuell" id="manuell" class="btn btn-danger manuell" accesskey="m">manuelle Eingabe - [Alt] + m</button></td>
<td align="center" width="25%"><input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" accesskey="s" value="neuer Vorgang - [Alt] + s"/></td>
<td align="right" Class="Gesamt">Gesamt: <span id="Gesamt"><?php print number_format(($Summe),2,',','.') . " €"; ?></span><input type="hidden" name="Summe" id="Summe" value=0/><input type="hidden" name="BasarNr" id="BasarNr" value="<?php print $BasarNr ?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><hr></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan='3' align="center" Class="SummeAlt"><a href="vorgang_zeigen.php?B=<?php print $BasarNr ?>&K=<?php print $KasseNr ?>&V=<?php print $Vorgang -1; ?>&D=<?php print $BasarDt ?>">Letzter Vorgang (Nr. <?php print $Vorgang -1; ?>)</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div class="well well-sm">&sup1; Preis manuell geändert</div>
</div>  
</form>
<div class="Gesamt" style="position: absolute;left: 2%;top: 100px;">
Gesamt: <span id="Gesamt"><?php print number_format(($Summe),2,',','.') . " €"; ?></span><input type="hidden" name="Summe" id="Summe" value=0/><input type="hidden" name="BasarNr" id="BasarNr" value="<?php print $BasarNr ?>"/>
</div>
</div>  
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="vorgang_edit" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <h4>Vorgang bearbeiten</h4>
            <form name='vorgang_bearbeiten' id='vorgang_bearbeiten' method='post' action='#' class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="idBasar">Basar ID:</label><div class="col-sm-6"><input class="form-control" type="number" name="idBasar" id="idBasar" value="" readonly /></div></div>
                <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="idKasse">Kasse Nr.:</label><div class="col-sm-6"><input class="form-control" type="number" name="idKasse" id="idKasse" value="" readonly /></div></div>
                <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="Vorgang">Vorgang Nr:</label><div class="col-sm-6"><input class="form-control" type="number" name="Vorgang" id="Vorgang" value="" readonly></div></div>
                <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="lfdNr">lfd. nr:</label><div class="col-sm-6"><input class="form-control" type="number" name="lfdNr" id="lfdNr" value="" readonly /></div></div>
                <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="Artikel">Artikel:</label><div class="col-sm-6"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="Artikel" id="Artikel" value="" readonly /></div></div>
                <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="Preis">neuer Preis:</label><div class="col-sm-6"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="Preis" id="Preis" value="" /></div></div>
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                <div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-success btn_add' type='button' name='speichern' id='speichern' >speichern</button></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Modal ende -->
</body>
<footer id="fussbereich" class="container">
</footer> 
</html>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){
    audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    var i=1;
    document.getElementById("Artikel").focus();
    $(document).on('click', '.manuell',function(){
        document.getElementById("Artikel").value='<?php print $BasarDtkurz . "-"; ?>';
        document.getElementById("Artikel").focus();
     });
    $('#add').click(function(){  
        $.ajax({  
            url:"vorgang_speichern.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:$('#neuer_Vorgang').serialize(),  
            success:function(data) {
                result= data.trim();
                if (result == "1") {
                                        var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
                    var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();

                    oscillator.connect(gainNode);
                    gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);

                    gainNode.gain.value = 0.5;
                    oscillator.frequency.value = 1000;
                    oscillator.type = 2;

                    oscillator.start();

                    setTimeout(
                        function(){
                            oscillator.stop();
                            $('#neuer_Vorgang')[0].reset();
                            location.reload(true );
                        }, 150);
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("Info").style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById("Info").className = "alert alert-danger Info";                      
                    document.getElementById("Info").innerHTML = "<a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>" + result;
                }
            } 
        });
    });  
    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
        $.ajax({  
            url:"vorgang_del.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{del: button_id},  
            success:function(data) {
                result= data.trim();
                if (result == "1") {
                    //$('#neuer_Vorgang')[0].reset();
                    location.reload(true );
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("Info").style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById("Info").className = "alert alert-danger Info";                      
                    document.getElementById("Info").innerHTML = "<a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>" + result;
                }
            } 
        });     

    });
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $.ajax({  
            url:"vorgang_add.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:$('#neuer_Vorgang').serialize(),  
            success:function(data) {
                result= data.trim();
                location.reload(true );
            } 
        });
    });
      $('#speichern').click(function(){
         document.getElementById("Meldung").style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById("Meldung").innerHTML = "";      
           $('#btn_edit').modal('hide');
         $.ajax({  
            url:"vorgang_preisaendern.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:$('#vorgang_bearbeiten').serialize(),  
            success:function(data) {
                result= data.trim();
                if (result == "1") {
                    $('#vorgang_bearbeiten')[0].reset();
                    location.reload(true );
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("Info").style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById("Info").className = "alert alert-danger Info";                      
                    document.getElementById("Info").innerHTML = "<a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>" + result;
                }
            } 
           });
      });

});

// Fenster mit Daten füllen
$(document).on("click", ".open-EditDialog", function () {
     var myvalues = $(this).data('id');
    var values = myvalues.split("_");
    $(".modal-body #idBasar").val(values[1]);
    $(".modal-body #idKasse").val(values[2]);
    $(".modal-body #Vorgang").val(values[3]);
    $(".modal-body #lfdNr").val(values[4]);
    $(".modal-body #Artikel").val(values[5]);
    $(".modal-body #Preis").val(values[6]);

});
// Fenster anzeigen
$('#btn_edit').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
    //alert("ready!");
    var button = e.relatedTarget; // Button that triggered the modal
    var btnval = button.id; // Extract info from data-* attributes
    // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
    // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
})
function checkcode (Nummer) {
    var x = document.getElementById("Artikel").value;
        $.ajax({  
            url:"vorgang_speichernpreis.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:$('#neuer_Vorgang').serialize(),  
            success:function(data) {
                result= data.trim();
                if (result == "1") {
                    $('#neuer_Vorgang')[0].reset();
                    location.reload(true );
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("Artikel").value='';
                    document.getElementById("Artikel").focus();
                    document.getElementById("Info").style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById("Info").className = "alert alert-danger Info";                      
                    document.getElementById("Info").innerHTML = "<a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>" + result;
                }
            } 
        });

};
</script>
```

and the second one:

```
<?php 
include 'connectdb.php';
$ShowDebugInfo=false;
if ( $db )
{
    // Verbindung zur Datenbank wurde hergestellt
    // Erst prüfen ob alle Datensätze geschrieben werden können, dann auch machen
    // WICHTIG - PRÜFEN OB DATTUM BARCODE STIMMT
    if ($ShowDebugInfo) {
        print_r($_POST);
        print"<br>\n";
    }
    $number = count($_POST["idBasar"]);
    $BasarNr = $_POST["BasarNr"];
    $_SESSION['SummeAlt'] = $_POST["Summe"];
    $_SESSION['VorgangAktuell'] = $_POST["Summe"];
    $savedb=true;
    $savedbErr = "";
    $Artikel=$_POST['Artikel'];
    if ($ShowDebugInfo) {print "Artikel: " . $Artikel . "<br>\n";}
    $ArtSplit=split("-",$Artikel);
    $DtBasar=$ArtSplit[0];
    if ($_POST['BasarDatum'] !=$DtBasar) {
        die("<b>Barcode ist ungültig! Datum " . $DtBasar . " ist falsch.</b>");
    }
    $TNNr=str_pad($ArtSplit[1], 3 ,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $ArtNr=str_pad($ArtSplit[2], 3 ,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $Artikel=$DtBasar."-" . $TNNr . "-" . $ArtNr;
    $sqlpreis ="SELECT * FROM ksb.artikel_" . $BasarNr . " where artikelnr=" . $ArtNr . " and teilnehmerNr=" . $TNNr . ";";

    if ($ShowDebugInfo) {
        print "DtBasar: " . $DtBasar . "<br>\n";
        print "TNNr: " . $TNNr . "<br>\n";
        print "ArtNr: " . $ArtNr . "<br>\n";
        print "sqlpreis: " . $sqlpreis . "<br>\n";
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sqlpreis);
    $Count=0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $Preis = $row['preis'];
        $Count++;
    }
    if ($Count >1) {
        die("<b>Mehr als ein Artikel gefunden!</b>");
    }
    if ($Count ==0) {
        die("<b>Kein Artikel gefunden!</b>");
    }

    if ($ShowDebugInfo) {
        print "Preis: " . $Preis . "<br>\n";
        $erg="Falsch";
        if ($Preis==''){$erg="Wahr";}
        print "Preis==''? " . $erg . "<br>\n";
        if ($Preis==0){$erg="Wahr";}
        print "Preis==0? " . $erg . "<br>\n";
        if (!isset($Preis)){$erg="Wahr";}
        print "!isset(\$Preis)? " . $erg . "<br>\n";
        if (is_null($Preis)){$erg="Wahr";}
        print "is_null(\$Preis)? " . $erg . "<br>\n";

    }

    if ($Preis=='' or $Preis==0 or !isset($Preis) or is_null($Preis)){
        echo('<b>Es wurde kein Preis erfasst! Preis für diesen Artikel bitte erfassen lassen.</b>');
    } else {
        if($number > 0) {
            $Zeitstempel = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $sqlFields = "INSERT INTO ksb.umsatz_" . $BasarNr . " (idBasar,idKasse,Vorgang,VorgangLfdNr,Preis,Zeitstempel,Artikel,teilnehmerNr,artikelnr) VALUES ";
            $sqlValues = "";
            if(trim($_POST["idBasar"]) != '' AND trim($_POST["idKasse"]) != '' AND trim($_POST["Vorgang"]) != '' AND trim($_POST["Artikel"]) != '') {
                $sqlValues .= "(" . $_POST["idBasar"] . "," . $_POST["idKasse"] . "," . $_POST["Vorgang"] . "," . $_POST["idlfdNr"] . "," . $Preis . ",'" . $Zeitstempel . "','" . $Artikel . "'," . $TNNr . "," . $ArtNr . ")";
                $_SESSION['VorgangLfdNr'] = $_POST['idlfdNr'];
            }  
            $sqlKompl = $sqlFields . $sqlValues;
            if ($ShowDebugInfo) {print "sqlKompl: " . $sqlKompl . "<br>\n";}
            if ($db->query($sqlKompl) === TRUE) {
                $_SESSION['Neu']=0;
                //Alles gut!
            } else {
                $Fehlermeldung = $db->error;
                $savedb=false;
                $FMeld = split ("'",$Fehlermeldung);
                if (trim($FMeld[0]) == 'Duplicate entry') {
                    $savedbErr .= "<b>Artikel bereits gebucht!</b>";
                } else {
                    $savedbErr .= "Fehler: " . $Fehlermeldung;
                }
            }
            if ($savedb) {
                echo "1";
            } else {
                echo $savedbErr;
            }
        } else {
            //Hier noch Fehler abfangen
            echo "Bitte Angaben prüfen!";  
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This is not a heavy load, so it is more likely there's a bug somewhere than that there are real performance problems. To find a bug in your script I should be able to run it, and I cannot without the database. A common mistake is doing a select query from two or more tables without joining them correctly. I don't see any of those. Next are endless loops. I don't get the for loop in your second script. It seems to loop `idBasar` times. Does that make sense to you? Possibly you're inserting far more data than you want? Anyway, what is `idBasar` exactly? An unique identifier? Is it?

Comment: Apache logs (err and access) -- any clues?  MySQL logs (not likely to provide any clues)?  CPU-bound?  I/O-bound?  `SHOW PROCESSLIST` showing a slow query?  Add more print statements to narrow down how far it gets before "hanging".